# Purpose of False GLFW_VISIBILE Hint While Binding OpenGL Context

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I'm currently following a tutorial that has the initialization code to create the window

```
private void init() {
    // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
    // will print the error message in System.err.
    errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err);
    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);

    // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
    }

    // Configure our window
    glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

    int WIDTH = 300;
    int HEIGHT = 300;

    // Create the window
    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
    }

    // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE) {
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true); // We will detect this in our rendering loop
            }
        }
    });

    // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    // Center our window
    glfwSetWindowPos(
            window,
            (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,
            (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2
    );

    // Make the OpenGL context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    // Enable v-sync
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // Make the window visible
    glfwShowWindow(window);
}
```

Notice the `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE);` hint is disabled, then after creating the window, setting the key callbacks, binding the opengl context, it's enabled again `glfwShowWindow(window);`

The documentation doesn't suggest doing anything like this, and removing both lines doesn't seem to change anything. **Why disable the hint in the first place**?

Tutorial: https://lwjglgamedev.gitbooks.io/3d-game-development-with-lwjgl/content/chapter1/chapter1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It disables visablity so it can set up the size, change position, and initialize the context without the client having to witness it. From the Window Visablity section in the [GLFW docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hide):

> Windowed mode windows can be created initially hidden with the
>   GLFW_VISIBLE window hint. Windows created hidden are completely
>   invisible to the user until shown. This can be useful if you need to
>   set up your window further before showing it, for example moving it to
>   a specific location.

Youre program follows that exact example by calling

```
glfwSetWindowPos(
            window,
            (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,
            (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2
    );
```

Comment: Had to wait for a specific amount of time before accepting